# Cloud Foundry - Spring Boot: How to open a URL in User's Browser?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I currently have a Spring Boot application deployed in the cloud through Cloud Foundry, and one of the functionalities is that it opens up the Google authentication URL in the User's browser when a specific controller endpoint is called.  When I am trying to call the endpoint and kick off the browser, I am getting this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "rundll32": error=2, No such file or directory
```

This works locally, but not sure why this file couldn't be found in the Java Runtime when it's deployed in CF.

The piece of code that calls this is below:

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you
Ryan

Comment: Most probably because 1. it's not part of the Java runtime and 2. Cloud Foundry runs on Linux servers, and not Windows. What you're trying to do doesn't seem to make much sense. You need to realize that your Java code runs on a server, not on your own machine.

Comment: But is there a way to open up the User's browser? @JBNizet

Comment: A Spring Boot application typically is a web application, and is thus accessed using a browser in the first place, just like you're currently accessing the StackOverflow application. So the browser is **already** open when using the application.

Comment: I think what youre looking for is a redirect

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in a Java app running on Cloud Foundry...

```
Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
runtime.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url);
```

Because it is trying to use a Windows DLL and the app running on CF will be running on Linux Cells.

> But is there a way to open up the User's browser?

No, not from your app. Your app is running on a remote server. If the remote server were able to do something like open a browser on a client's computer then it could do all sorts of things, good or bad, and you'd have major security problems.

If you're in a Windows environment perhaps your Windows admins could push out a shared bookmark/desktop shortcut to all your clients/users which links to your app? That'd make it easier for them to go to the service.

Hope that helps!